# Set local value in phpinfo

Tags: php, file-upload

My system is windows with appserv9.3.0.

I have set up my php.ini both upload_max_filesize and post_max_size with 1000GB, but when I upload file, it's say limit 20mb.
I checked phpinfo, the local value of post_max_size is 20mb.

I found out all the setting, but not found where to set local value.

Please help me to set the local value, thx a lot.

Comment: Check webserver settings as well...

Comment: Check **Loaded Configuration File** value in phpinfo first, make sure it is php.ini that you just edited.

Comment: The server where under the promox. I've check Loaded Configuration File is correct path, but when I edit php.ini, the local value still not change.

Comment: Have you tried to restart apache?

Comment: Thx all, I've find out the answer. The htaccess has hidden in my www folder, I've edit it, and it got work!